# Cast object and return from method

Tags: c#

I have following classes as below:

```
class Animal {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Dog : Animal {
}

class Cat : Animal {
    public int CatType { get; set; }
    public int CatLoc { get; set; }
}
```

As shown `Cat` contains `two more fields`. I have method that returns collection of `Animals` and argument `Sector`. This method has to return either colection of `Cat` or collection of `Dog` depending on `Sector`. If passed `Sector = Sector.RT` my method needs to query additionally two fields for `Cat` from `database`. I got problems with converting and filling `animal variable` when `Sector = Sector.RT` in `if (sector == sector.RT) ...` because `CatType` and `CatLoc` are unknown at this point and then correctly returns valid object. How should i do this properly? Hope explained well.

```
public IEnumerable<Animal> GetData(Sector sector)
{
    var animal = new Animal();
    var additionalCat = $"CatType, CatLoc ";
    
    var query = $"SELECT Id, Name, " +
                $"{(sector == SectorEnum.RT ? additionalCat : string.Empty)} " +
                $"FROM Animals";
                
    using var conn = Context.GetDbConn();
    using var cmd = Context.GetCommand(query, conn, CommandType.Text);
    using var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        animal = new Animal();
        for (var i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0) animal.Id = (int)reader[i];
            if (i == 1) animal.Name = (string)reader[i];
        }
        
        if (sector == sector.RT)
        {
            animal = (Cat)animal;
            //Convert animal to Cat and add two more field 
            //ISSUE: CatType and CatLoc are unknown at this point !
            if (i == 2) animal.CatType = (int)reader[i];
            if (i == 3) animal.CatLoc =  (int)reader[i];
        }
        
        yield return animal;
}
```

Comment: You have to actually construct a `Cat` instance. Casting does not change the type of the object.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen You mean i cannot cast Cat to Animal or vice versa?

Comment: You can't cast an object of actual type `Animal` to type `Cat`, because it isn't the right type. You can cast `Cat` to `Animal` because that is a simple reference cast, you're holding on to a cat, as an animal, but you can't do the opposite. The answer below answers it perfectly.

Comment: You can use a `Cat` in place of an `Animal`. If a `Cat` instance is typed as `Animal`, you can cast to a `Cat` because it **is** a `Cat`. e.g. `Animal animal = new Cat(); Cat cat = (Cat)animal;`

Comment: Unless you add conversion operators, which actually construct new objects, casting objects in .NET does not change the type of the object, it only changes the type of the reference, but the change has to be legal.

Comment: In case `sector != sector.RT` then your `query` will be `SELECT Id, Name, FROM Animals`. Here `,` should not be there after `Name`. It will throw exception I guess.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen So i can cast Dog/Cat to Animal but not vice versa? Why then compiler allows for that

Comment: The compiler doesn't know that the underlying object is of the wrong type. You're allowed to change the type of the reference as long as the object is of, or inherits from, that type. You're not allowed to change the type of the reference to something else. The underlying object is *not* a `Cat`, nor does it inherit from `Cat`, so you can't change the reference to type `Cat`. However, if the underlying object *is* a `Cat`, then you can cast to `Animal`, because `Cat` inherits from `Animal`. In other words, you can treat a cat as an animal, but you can't treat all animals as cats.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen So for instance i could cast Cat to Animal like Animal myAnimal= new Cat(); therefore i would know that i have in fact Cat in myAnimal variable so i also could cast back right? : Cat realCat= (Cat) myAnimal; So simply saying i can cast Cat to Animal only when in myAnimal would be casted Cat ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it, cause `Animal` is not `Cat` (see this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions) for example), you need to instantiate correct class from the start. Something like this:

```
 while (reader.Read())
 {
     if (sector == sector.RT)
     {
          var cat  = new Cat();            
          cat.CatType = (int)reader[2];
          cat.CatLoc =  (int)reader[3];
          animal = cat;
     }
     else
     {
         animal = new Animal();
     }
     animal.Id = (int)reader[0];
     animal.Name = (string)reader[1];
     yield return animal;
}
```

Comment: can you also include for i = 0 and i = 1 i want to see something

Comment: thanks but could you also just include my for loop ? This will be diffrent i suppose there

Comment: @Arie TBH I do't understand why do you need `for` loop there - cause you are kind of defeating purpose of it with `if` statements (like `if (i == 0)`)

Comment: you right i removed it. So it means i Can cast from Cat to Animal but I cannot cast from animal to Cat ?

Comment: @Arie yes, exactly, cause every `Cat` is `Animal` but not every `Animal` is `Cat`. Please read the docs I've linked to the post, and also [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/inheritance)

Comment: so this is not allowed: Animal myAnimal =  new Animal(); and then Cat myCat = (Cat) myAnimal; BUT if i would do: Animal myAnimal =  new Cat(); so then Cat myCat  = (Cat) myAnimal; would work am i right?

Comment: so simply saying i COULD cast animal to cat ONLY when that animal is real Cat (animal was casted to Cat before)

Comment: Yes, also yo can [type check](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast) that your `Animal myAnimal` is actually a Cat so you would not end with error in runtime.

Comment: so you confirm my last two comments, Is my thinking right?

Comment: @Arie yes, `Animal myAnimal = new Animal(); Cat myCat = (Cat) myAnimal;` will throw in runtime, while `Animal myAnimal = new Cat(); Cat myCat = (Cat) myAnimal;` will work.

Comment: Strong I do understand. Last thing:  What would happen in second valid scenario. When Animal myAnimal = new Cat(CatLoc = 12); my question is how CatLoc (which exist only in Cat) can be saved when i set it to Animal (myAnimal)? I thought when save in Animal would erase additional cat's properties values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218274/discussion-between-guru-stron-and-arie).

Answer (score 1):

I would construct the animal on the fly:

```
public IEnumerable<Animal> GetData(Sector sector)
{
    Animal animal;
    var additionalCat = $"CatType, CatLoc ";
    
    var query = $"SELECT Id, Name, " +
                $"{(sector == SectorEnum.RT ? additionalCat : string.Empty)} " +
                $"FROM Animals";
                
    using var conn = Context.GetDbConn();
    using var cmd = Context.GetCommand(query, conn, CommandType.Text);
    using var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (sector == sector.RT)
        {
            Cat cat = new Cat();     
            cat.CatType = (int)reader[2];
            cat.CatLoc =  (int)reader[3];
            animal = cat;
        }
        
        else
        {
            animal = new Dog();          
        }
        animal.Id = (int)reader[0];
        animal.Name = (string)reader[1];
        
        yield return animal;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but imagine you would have 20 common fields not 2. THen we duplciate a lot :/

Comment: can you also include with my for loop? I think it complicates staff.

Comment: updated it - why you need the for loop ? you're accessing directly the reader.

Comment: there is issue i think when you say: animal = new Cat(); then CatType and CatLock not available..

Answer (score 0):

Creating A "Base Table"
We can start by recognizing that Cats, dogs are all "Animal"
In the Animal table, we'd store all of the common attributes of cats and dogs that you discussed earlier: id, name and so on. We remove all of these common columns from the dogs and cats tables and put them all in one place.

Deriving Sub-Tables from the Base Table
Of course, we still need our dogs and cats tables but now the primary key of these tables also becomes a foreign key to the Animal table .Because any row in the cats, dogs  tables require a related row in the People table and it also shares the same primary key as the Animal table (i.e., it is a 1:1 relation)

Think of these sub-tables as tables that extend the basic information that the Animal table provides; this is similar to how inheritance works in Object-Oriented Programming (OOP). Essentially, we are performing "table inheritance" by doing this; since every cats and dogs is by definition also an "animal" and we are guaranteed that we can work with all of those entities the same way by treating them as Animal if we want, or we can work with them using their specific attributes and relations.

That gives us a schema like this:

create table Animal(id int primary key, Name varchar ... etc ...)

create table dogs(id int primary key references Animal(id), ...)

create table cats(id int primary key references Animal(id), ...)

With that particular schema, notice a few things:
You cannot create a cat/dog until you first set up the "Animal". Once the animal is created, you can now add a related row to the appropriate table, depending what type they are.

and now after a log time ;) your answer is
If we want to output a "Type" column (dog, cat) when querying the Animal table, we must outer join to all the 2"sub-tables" and determine if any matching rows exist.

```
select c.*, a.*
from cats c 
inner join Animal a on c.id= a.id
```